# Permutations of a list in Haskell without using Data.Set

Tags: haskell, permutation, combinatorics

I have to write a Haskell function that gives **all** possible permutations of a given list.

The type signature has to be:

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

For example, an acceptable result is (under `ghci`):

```
λ>
λ> permutations [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[1,3,2],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
λ>
```

The following restrictions apply:

1. Plain lists are the sole authorized data structure, so no `Set` or `Vector`.
2. The permutations may be produced in any order.
3. The function must work for any element type, i.e. no `Ord a` or `Eq a` instances.
4. Only library functions from the standard Prelude may be used.

Does anyone know how I could do it ?

Comment: There is a concept of “the *next* permutation” after the current one. See the [C++ version of it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) for example. The *next* permutation may exist, or not. For example, your [3,2,1] is the one having no successor in the lexicographic order. Now, say if you wrote first a `nextPermutation :: [Int] -> Maybe [Int]` building block, you might be able to come up with a recursive version of your `permutations` function.

Comment: Very often, recursion is used (although not per se explicitly). You thus can first try to implement a function that performs the permutation of 0 elements, 1 element, 2 elements, and then solve the problem with *n* elements in terms of *n-1* elements.

Comment: If Vector and Set data types are disallowed, the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm) seems convenient.

Comment: Within the SJT algorithm, an essential building block is the `spread` function. Expression `spread 4 [1,2,3]` puts 4 at all possible positions within [1,2;3] : `[[4,1,2,3],[1,4,2,3],[1,2,4,3],[1,2,3,4]]`. To get all permutations of [1,2,3,4], you just need to use `spread 4` on all permutations of [1,2,3]. So you have a base case: `permutations [] = [[]]` and a compound case: `permutations (x:xs) = concat (map (spread x) (permutations xs))` . And it is not that difficult to write a recursive implementation of function `spread`.

Comment: This question is very similar to [a later one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70461087/haskell-permutations-with-very-limited-functions).

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to approach this problem. jpmarinier suggest one possible way in the comments, but I think a recursive approach following the structure of the input list is more natural in Haskell.

For that recursive approach you have to implement what needs to happen in the case the list is empty and what needs to happen in the case that the list contains at least one element and in this case you can also use the function recursively on the rest of the list. The general structure is:

```
permutations [] = _
permutations (x:xs) = let xs' = permutations xs in _
```

The case with the empty list is pretty simple, but there are a few different choices that make the compiler happy, so it might not be immediately clear which one you should choose.

For the case with at least one element I would use a second helper function called `splits :: [Int] -> [([Int],[Int])]` which computes all possible splits of the input list into two lists.

Here an example input and output that might make it more clear what I mean:

```
splits [1,2,3] == [([],[1,2,3]),([1],[2,3]),([1,2],[3]),([1,2,3],[])]
```

The implementation of this function is also recursive and follows the same pattern:

```
splits [] = _
splits (x:xs) = let xs' = splits xs in _
```

Comment: Why do you think there's more than one sensible answer for the empty list? All signs point to one specific answer.

Comment: There is one conventional answer, but I think it is easy to make the "mistake" of picking the "wrong" answer. Nevertheless, I think rewording it from "sensible" to "makes the compiler happy" avoids this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article on permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) leads us to, among many other things, the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm), which seems well suited to linked lists.

For this algorithm, an essential building block is a function we could declare as:

```
spread :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

For example, expression `spread 4 [1,2,3]` has to put 4 at all possible positions within [1,2;3], thus evaluating to: `[[4,1,2,3],[1,4,2,3],[1,2,4,3],[1,2,3,4]]`. To get all permutations of [1,2,3,4], you just need to apply `spread 4` to all permutations of [1,2,3]. And it is easy to write `spread` in recursive fashion:

```
spread :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
spread x [] = [[x]]
spread x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : (map (y:) (spread x ys))
```

And permutations can thus be obtained like this:

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations [] = [[]]
permutations (x:xs) = concat (map (spread x) (permutations xs))
```

Comment: **Note:** this answer is derived from an [answer to a later, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70471446/11282404) which was written while the current question happened to be temporarily under a “*Closed*” status.