# Haskell Permutations with very limited functions

Tags: haskell, permutation, whitelist

I have to implement a function in haskell that takes a list `[Int]` and gives a list `[[Int]]` with all permutations, but i'm only allowed to use:
`[]`, `:`, `True`, `False`, comparisons, `&&`, `||`, and `not`

```
permutations [] = [[]]
permutations xs = [(y:zs) | (y,ys) <- picks xs, zs <- permutations ys]
   where
   picks (x:xs) = (x,xs) : [(y,x:ys) | (y,ys) <- picks xs]
```

My idea was to use something like that but i have to replace the `<-`

Comment: `<-` is not a function, it is part of the *list comprehension* syntax (i.e. the `[ ... | ... <- ... ]`). I would ask if you are allowed to use list comprehensions. I assume that some other syntactic constructs are allowed as well, like `=` and `where`, but those are admittedly more fundamental than list comprehensions.

Comment: Section 3.11 of [the Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf) defines exactly how the list comprehension is supposed to behave in terms of `let` expressions and `concatMap` (which, if you can't use, is easily reimplemented in as low-level detail as fits your constraints).

Comment: This question looks very similar to [an earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70439676/permutations-of-a-list-in-haskell-without-using-data-set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by chepner in the comments, a few missing elementary library functions can easily be re-implemented “on the spot”.

The [Wikipedia article on permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) leads us to, among many other things, the [Steinhaus–Johnson–Trotter algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm), which seems well suited to linked lists.

For this algorithm, an essential building block is a function we could declare as:

```
spread :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

For example, expression `spread 4 [1,2,3]` has to put 4 at all possible positions within [1,2;3], thus evaluating to: `[[4,1,2,3],[1,4,2,3],[1,2,4,3],[1,2,3,4]]`. To get all permutations of [1,2,3,4], you just need to apply `spread 4` to all permutations of [1,2,3]. And it is easy to write `spread` in recursive fashion:

```
spread :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
spread x [] = [[x]]
spread x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : (map (y:) (spread x ys))
```

And permutations can thus be obtained like this:

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations [] = [[]]
permutations (x:xs) = concat (map (spread x) (permutations xs))
```

Overall, a rules-compliant version of the source code would go like this, with its own local versions of the `map` and `concat` Prelude functions:

```
permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
permutations  []     =  [[]]
permutations (x:xs)  =  myConcat (myMap (spread x) (permutations xs))
  where
    myMap fn  []     =  []
    myMap fn (z:zs)  =  (fn z) : (myMap fn zs)

    myConcat   []          =  []
    myConcat ([]:zss)      =  myConcat zss
    myConcat ((z:zs):zss)  =  z : (myConcat (zs:zss))

    spread z []      =  [[z]]
    spread z (y:ys)  =  ( z:y:ys) : (myMap (y:) (spread z ys))
```